# Does anyone have a version of the 50x50 article by Nikita Plaksin?

Tags: history, books, problems, 50-move-rule

In 1979, Nikita M. Plaksin published a reportedly fascinating article containing 50 problems all related to the 50 moves rule. Unfortunately I can't find it anywhere, the only links that I could find are old and broken.

If anyone has it, would you please share it with the community and not let it get lost to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last night, to my surprise, my reasking of this question over on the [Matplus.net forums](http://www.matplus.net/start.php?px=1570619082&app=forum&act=posts&fid=gen&tid=2341&pid=18003#n18003) about received an; answer. There, a user by the name of Valery Liskovets provided a link to a PDF of the original article, which has pictures of all of the pages.

Here is the link: http://www.janko.at/Retros/Articles/Plaksin-50x50-Problem-1979.pdf

Comment: This answer deserves at least 50 upvotes :) thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hi Arnaud thanks for your question.

The problems themselves can all be found in pdb.dieschwalbe.de. Type K='50' AND A='Plaksin' AND S='Problem' AND YEAR='1979'. All 50 are there numbered, with solutions. If you are typing from a phone make sure that you select the correct single-quote character: the vertical one.

The query reveals that they were published in the now-defunct magazine Problem, but it does not give the article text. I suggest Arnaud that you send your request to the Retro Mailing List retros@janko.at. This will put you in touch with all the current retro greats who would probably love to hear from you.

If that doesn’t work then let me know and I will approach someone individually.

EDIT: the 50x50 article is now available at https://www.janko.at/Retros/Articles/index.htm in Russian but I guess that google translate will work - and the diagrams are the not important part.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will do this.

Comment: Note: for me, the string of keywords doesn't work as such, but K=50 AND A='Plaksin' AND S='Problem' AND YEAR=1979 does (although it will not output only stuff from 1979).

Comment: hi Arnaud - there was a tiny typo in the command sorry - the last quote sign ' had defaulted to apostrophe ’ . That’s easy to miss on phone - have fixed that in my earlier post. The year parameter must be included in quotes in order to be used.